# Removing an Axis in d3js Parallel Coordinates

Tags: d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I'm attempting to implement a function where if I click an axis, the column of data will be removed from the parallel coordinates graph. However, it seems to only remove the axis versus removing the data underneath it. The functionality I'm looking for is similar to http://bl.ocks.org/syntagmatic/3150059 where dragging a column to the left-edge will remove it from the graph.

```js
parcoords.svg.selectAll(".dimension")
  .on("click", delete_axis);

function delete_axis(dimension) {
  parcoords.svg.selectAll(".dimension")
    .filter(function(d) {
      return d == dimension;
    }).remove();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `.on("click", function() { d3.select(this).remove(); })`?

Comment: I get the same behavior in which the axis disappears but the lines of data still behave as if the column is there.

Comment: Oh I see. For that, you'll have to update the domains of the scales you're using with the non-removed data and then redraw the existing lines.

Comment: I guess that's what I'm missing. How do I trigger a redrawing of the lines?

Comment: Call the code to set the `d` attribute again.

Answer (score 0):

do you use the parallel coordinates library? https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates

if so you have two possibilities:
hide the axes you don't want to show (completely; no influence on the plot).
here param is an array of the name of the axes not to be shown (as strings)

```
parcoords.hideAxis(param)
 .render()
 .updateAxes();
```

only show the ones you want to( the others have completely no influence ).
here param is an array of the names of the shown axes (as strings).

```
parcoords
 .detectDimensions()
 .dimensions(param)
 .render()
 .updateAxes();
```

greetings Jones